# How to deduce the function from the graph?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

How to deduce the function from the graph?[image]

It is given that the degree of numerator of f(x) is 2

** My Attempt**

There are two asymptotes so the denominator should be in the form $k(x+2)(x-1)$. And I can see there are two stationary points on the graph at $x=-5,x=-1$But I'm confused on how to use this in deducing function of the graph. Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In general, it's impossible to deduce, there should be more information about the function. Are we to assume that it's a rational function? Even then, the degree of the numerator should also be given.

Comment: Numerator degree is not given. But yes we assume the function as a rational function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: there is a single root at $x=-3$ and the numerator must be of order less that the denominator since the $x$ axis is an asymptote. Hence the function will be of the form

$$y=\frac{\lambda(x+3)}{(x+2)(x-1)}$$

If you differentiate this you will indeed find the correct $x$ values for the given stationary points so you just have to determine the value of $\lambda$.

Can you finish?

Comment: After differentiation I was able to derive the value for $\lambda$=2

Comment: Thank you. I understood it well!

Comment: you are welcome